# Use escape key to cancel inline tinyMCE edit

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'd like a user to be able to use the escape key to abort any changes in a tinyMCE editor in inline mode. Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="tinymce">
  <p>Foo Foo Foo</p>
</div>
```

And the script:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#tinymce',
  inline: true,
  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('keydown', ((e) => {
      var tinyMceEditor = tinyMCE.get(e.target.id);

      if (e.keyCode === 27) { // escape
        // This will hide the editor but it won't come back when trying to re-edit
        tinyMceEditor.hide();
      }
    }));
  }
});
```

It's also a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kfnyqufm/

Hitting escape closes the editor like I want but has two issues: (1) the editor doesn't return when clicking the text (2) any edited text doesn't revert to the original value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1) the editor doesn't return when clicking the text**

This happens because you are hiding the editor completely when <kbd>esc</kbd>  is pressed, and not showing it again. You have (at least) two options to solve this:

1. Show the editor when the `#tinymce` div gets focus again; or
2. Trigger the `blur()` method on the `#tinymce` when <kbd>esc</kbd> is pressed (that will automatically hide the editor, and it will come back on click again)

If you go with the second option (I think it would be simpler), the code would be like this (only the part related to the escape button):

```
if (e.keyCode === 27) { // escape
    document.getElementById("tinymce").blur();
}
```

You can also see it on [this version of your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kfnyqufm/1/).

**(2) any edited text doesn't revert to the original value**

This is a bit trickier (but still simple) as you'll need to keep track of the old value and restore if <kbd>esc</kbd> is pressed. The logic for this would be:

- When the `#tinymce` div gets focus: save the inner HTML into a JavaScript variable (or in the `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`).
- When the escape key is pressed: restore the saved value as the inner HTML of `#tinymce`.

The code would be something like this for storing the old value:

```
// define a variable to store the old value
var old_value = "";

// save the old value when #tinymce gets focus
document.getElementById("tinymce").addEventListener("focus", function() {
  old_value = document.getElementById("tinymce").innerHTML;
}, false);
```

And then you'd need to also restore the old value when <kbd>esc</kbd> is pressed:

```
if (e.keyCode === 27) { // escape
    // blur the tinymce div and restore the old value
    document.getElementById("tinymce").blur();
    document.getElementById("tinymce").innerHTML = old_value;
}
```

You can see it fully working on [this version of your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kfnyqufm/2/).

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you!